# Showing that $f(u,v) = (u,v,u^2-v^2)$ is a parametrization.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-topology, parametrization

**Exercise :**

> Let $f(u,v) = (u,v,u^2-v^2), \; (u,v) \in U$ where $U$ is a coherent and open subset of $\mathbb R^2$. Show that $f$ is a parametrization of a $C^\infty$ patch (local surface) of a surface $\Phi$.

**Attempt/Question :**

I know that in order to show that $f$ is a **regular** parametrization (I don't know and cannot find the cases just for "parametrization"), one needs to show that the function $f: U \to \Phi$ is injective and onto, while also $f_u \times f_v \neq 0 $ everywhere in $U$.

It is $f_u \times f_v = (-2u,2v,1) \neq \mathbf{0} \; \forall (u,v) \in U$.

I am having trouble showing that $f$ is injective and onto though, any guidance will be appreciated.

Though, the following question arises :

**Question :** When is $f$ just simply called a parametrization ? I assume, that when $f$ is injective and onto, while also smooth. That takes the $f_u \times f_v \neq \mathbf{0}$ out.

**As a starter in Differential Geometry I would really appreciate any thorough explanations.**

P.S. : I apologise if any term is mistakenly stated, as I am trying to properly translate the terms and the exercise from Greek.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of a Monge patch. It's easy to see that $f$ is injective, $f$ is onto $\Phi:=f(U)$ ($\Phi$ was never defined, so I assume that it is $f(U)$; note that it will be a subset of a hyperbolic paraboloid), and $f$ is smooth. As you noted, $f_u\times f_v\neq 0$ on $U$, and so $f$ is regular. So, we've shown everything that we need to.

As for terminology, it differs. I've often seen the definition that a regular map $f:U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ whose image lies in a surface $M$ is called a parameterization of the region $f(U)$ in $M$, meaning that a patch is an injective parameterization.

EDIT: $f$ is always onto its image, so we just need to show that $f$ is injective. Suppose that $f(x,y)=f(u,v).$ Then, $$(x,y,x^2-y^2)=(u,v,u^2-v^2).$$ Since the coordinates must be equal, we have that \begin{align*} x&=u\\y&=v\\x^2-y^2&=u^2-v^2,\end{align*} and so $x=u, y=v,$ and $(x,y)=(u,v).$

Comment: How to show that $f$ is injective and $f$ is onto ? I haven't totally grasped the essence of these meanings for the differential geometry cases. Also, I didn't quite get the difference in the last terminology regarding parametrization.

Comment: @Rebellos edited

Comment: As for the terminology, I'm saying that it depends on your book. I've seen books where they only define a parameterization, not a regular parameterization (where the assumption is that the map is regular). Regularity is a basic smoothness condition that is standard.

Comment: Okay, as simple as that then! I thought a more delicate statement shall be used. Thanks a lot for the help and the swift replies !

Comment: @Rebellos No problem!